# Enforce right orientation landscape mode for Phonegap/Cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, orientation, screen-orientation

Is it possible to enforce your Phonegap app to use right landscape orientation mode only?

I know this is possible for a native iOS app (see screenshot of setting in Xcode) [image]

The only thing for Phonegap I can find is the orientation preference in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

This preference enforces to show the app in landscape mode but allows you to rotate your screen 180 degrees. This isn't the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" overwrite="true">
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Where did you add that?

Comment: In your config.xml file. Note: this solution works when you build your app using build.phonegap.com. If you build using Cordova (local), you can set the screen orientation setting in your info.plist file.

Here you can find more info about this setting: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html

Comment: Also needs a `</gap:config-file>` but did not solve my problem with app starting with the wrong rotation on Ipad.

Answer (score 2):

For IOS

In config.xml set:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"></preference>
```

or

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"></preference>
```

In "ProjectName"-info.plist file in ios folder under resources folder for "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" set:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

or

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

or

for portrait orientation:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
```

or

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
```

Include which is applicable for your requirements.